Icon doesnt show in Iphone when added to bookmark
Here is the code:

<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="favicon/apple-touch-icon.png?id=4229946c20961e9f08cb4ea88c109d24">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="favicon/favicon-32x32.png?id=028cb384c57522e451f2fbb2bf9c13cd">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="favicon/favicon-16x16.png?id=701fb5a3408071cae3161d40b1d3d2ac">
<link rel="mask-icon" href="favicon/safari-pinned-tab.svg?id=5002668b36ce6567d611f862e9387da5" color="#7dcfe6">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon/favicon.ico?id=308aefa94e2ec3085dddec4b0cf1eddf">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#00aba9">
<meta name="msapplication-config" content="favicon/browserconfig.xml?id=aa969479da9d89b3169173fae9fe0d01">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">


was there something I missed to add?
preview:

